# Drawing over an image in win32?

Tags: winapi, gdi, codeblocks

First of all, keep in mind that I am a beginner in win32, so I am very likely to be missing the obvious.

I am working with Code::Blocks, C++, win32. I am making a program that:

1. would load an image from a file
2. would load some info from another file and draw it over the image.

The program would then draw additional stuff over the image later on. Also, I don't need this drawing to be actually incorporated into the image, the image only acts as a reference for the drawing.

I have managed to display the image in a child (static) window and I have successfully drawn the info onto the main window. When I wanted to combine the two so the drawing would go over the image, however, I got stuck - I didn't know what window to draw to and which message to process for the drawing. I have searched the Internet for any hints, examples, anything, but I found nothing. (This is probably because I didn't know exactly how to describe my problem.)

I have been trying different things over the past few days, like drawing to the static control with the image, and trying to paint to a transparent static control on top of the one for the image, but nothing worked.

If anyone could give me any hints, that would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Trap the `WM_PAINT` message for the window you want to draw. In the handler, add code draw the image (`BitBlt` function perhaps) first and then the drawing you want. You must also handle `WM_ERASEBKGND` message which is used to erase the background of the window when re-sizing etc.

Refer: [WM_PAINT message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145213%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [WM_ERASEBKGND message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648055%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)